# Modify excel file in python on linux enviroment

Tags: python, linux, excel

how do i insert few row in an existing excel file using python? the excel file maybe be of any excel version. On windows that could have been possible by using win32com.client...but i need to make the changes in the linux environment. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [pyExcelerator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyExcelerator/). the package comes with example demos to write excel files

Comment: xlwt is a fork of pyExcelerator so the demos are probably the same. 
Based on this 

http://groups.google.com/group/python-excel/browse_thread/thread/ea65395fc7856bee

I would say that pyExcelerator is no longer maintained

Comment: @ghostdog74: pyExcelerator has a bad case of the Norwegian Blue Parrot syndrome. xlwt has extra functionality, better speed, uses less memory and has a tutorial ... see http://www.python-excel.org

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into this myself and found https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/wiki/Home .
It is a new library that allows editing xlsx files.